# Can yearly tax free gifts to a person in the U.S. be sent in multiple checks?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, gift-tax

I'd like to give someone a monetary gift, well under the current $14,000 Annual Gift Tax Exclusion limit; however, I'd like to send them multiple checks throughout the year. I'd heard about this in my high school economics class, and the teacher phrased it as a "yearly one time gift."

Is this okay, or must the gift be sent all at once?

Do I need to keep copies of the checks myself, or should I tell the recipient to keep copies of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can split the gifts as many ways you want. The 'one time a year' limit means that you cannot gift twice the limit in two installations and avoid the gift tax; the *total value* can be once per year tax free if it is not over the limit.

Comment: Confirmed with my Financial Advisor. I appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 9):

Gift taxes are owed by you, not the recipient, so you are the one that would need to keep copies of the checks.

Comment: This makes sense. There's nowhere I have to report them UNLESS they go over the $14,000 limit correct? In that case, I will pay taxes on the gift.

Comment: Yup, under the 14,000 limit, there is no necessary reporting.

Comment: If I could mark 2 answers I would. Thank you for your helpful responses.